# How to prevent the user from selecting an option from nextcord.ui.Select

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

I wanted to implement a list of options where the user cannot select anything.

#### I tried the following:

- Read the Nextcord documentation. They do not offer any way to achieve this.
- Look at the source code to see if I could create a class derived from ui.Select that does not send data to Discord and thus force a failed interaction (since I saw that failed interactions cancel the user's selection).
- Set within the ui.Select callback the values ​​attribute to an empty list. But it sends me the error "Can't set attribute".
- Call asyncio.sleep to put the callback to sleep until Discord considers the interaction failed. But that although it works, produces an ugly error in console.

#### Conclusion

I came to the conclusion that throwing a Python error on the callback would be the only way I could recognize of forcing a failed interaction and thus preventing the user from selecting something. But I don't like to generate an error with the sole objective of interrupting the course of the code.

#### Ask

How can I make the user unable to select anything from the ui.Select? Or, if this is not possible, how can I force a failed interaction every time the user selects something?

#### Edit

I forgot to add a minimal, complete and verifiable example to you so you can test, excuse me.

```
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord import ui
import nextcord

import asyncio

#-----------------------------------------------#
# Bot
#-----------------------------------------------#

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    view = ui.View()

    select = ui.Select(options=[nextcord.SelectOption(label="option1"), nextcord.SelectOption(label="option2")])
    view.add_item(select)

    await ctx.send("Test Message", view=view)
        
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot listo!")

bot.run(bot_key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no official way to do this, there are a few workarounds:

### First method: Overriding `interaction_check`:

The [`interaction_check`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=view#nextcord.ui.View.interaction_check) function is called every time an interaction is dispatched, and the interaction will only be responded to, if this function returns `True`. So if this function always returns `False`, the interaction will always fail, resulting in "This interaction failed" and resetting the choice in the select in discord:

```py
async def interaction_check(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    return False
```

You can then add this function to the select in the same way as you add the callback function.

### Second method: Editing the message:

This is the cleaner option, since it doesn't show "This interaction failed" in discord and has a shorter waiting time in resetting the choice. This works by simply editing the message, but not changing anything:

```py
async def callback(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    await interaction.edit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! At first it didn't work, but I updated nextcord and the second solution works fine! I will put you in the credits of my bot as a thank you c: By the way, I kept the second solution, since as you say it is cleaner.